# Is the phrase "the alive animal" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives

Is it wrong to use the phrase "The alive animal"?

Is it alright to say, "The animal was alive."?

Comment: I have problems with adjectives preceding nouns and after linking verbs. Some can be used before nouns and after linking verbs such as high, hot...

Comment: Most adjectives can be used both before nouns and after linking verbs. There are a few exceptions, which you just have to learn.

Answer (score 9):

*The animal was alive* is a correct sentence.  *The alive animal* is a noun phrase and therefore not a sentence, since at the very least it is missing a verb.

Having said that, I interpret the question as asking whether it is possible to place the adjective *alive* in front of a noun. In other words, can *alive* be used attributively? Most adjectives can be used both attributively (before the noun) and predicatively (following a copula such as the verbs *to be, to seem, to look*). So *happy* can be used both attributively and predicatively:

- The *happy* child [played in the sand].
- The child looked *happy*.

But some adjectives can only be used predicatively; they cannot be used attributively. *Alive* is one such adjective, so *the alive animal* is ungrammatical. There are many other non-attributive adjectives beginning with the letter *a*. For example, it is ungrammatical to say:

- *the afraid child ..
- *the asleep child ..
- *the alone child ..

Other adjectives can only be used attributively; they cannot be used predicatively. For example:

- my maiden aunt (*my aunt is maiden)
- my sole pleasure (*my pleasure is sole).

Comment: Really?  I don't agree with this.  "The dead animal is here, the alive animal is there." is a perfectly valid sentence in my book.

Comment: @Jez I'm glad I'm not the only one!

Comment: @Jez, The *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (p559) lists *alive* in its group of *"very clearly non-attributive adjectives"*, and denotes phrases such as *an asleep child* as *"strongly ungrammatical"*. There is nothing to stop anyone using such adjectives attributively, but it is helpful for the non-native speakers on this site to know what authoritative grammars have to say on the issue.

Comment: @Jez, how about "There was an alive animal there"? Also, Shoe is right about "alive"; however, Huddleston and Pullum (the authors of Chapter 6 in the CGEL) argue that "expansion by modification or coordination can greatly improve the acceptability of the attributive use: compare *their awake children and their still awake children or *She flashed me an aware glance with the attested She flashed me an aware, amused glance" (p. 559).

Comment: Is any of us concerned with whether the answers/ comments are helping the OP in some way? Or are we more about proving a point here?

Comment: @user20908, At the risk of trying to prove a point, I think you will find that the cut and thrust in the comments sections on this site often brings out some nuances or extra information not covered in the original answer and leads to a better understanding of the issue, which is rarely as black and white as the original answer might suggest. Whether the OP finds that to be true in this particular case, is up to him or her to say. But I think you have the germ of an interesting question about the function of comments to be asked over on meta.

Answer (score 0):

The ***live*** animal

If you insist on using the word *alive*, then:
*The animal, **alive***

Comment: How about "The animal was alive"?

Comment: "*The animal was alive.*" is a sentence. "*The live animal*"/ "*The animal, live*" are phrases (parts of a sentence). It depends on how you want to use. Can you give us the context?

Comment: the live animal and the living animal. What's the difference?

Comment: *Living animal* is not a proper phrase. An animal is a living thing -- something that lives, as opposed to, say, a stone that's a non-living thing. An animal that is alive is a *live animal*.

Comment: 'Living animal' is a proper phrase, and according to Ngram used more than 'live animal'    >  http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=living+animal%2C+live+animal&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3

Comment: @Roaring Fish & his up voters: Have you bothered to check the context where the two words are found adjacent? You will be surprised.

Comment: Okay... 'World's oldest living animal discovered after he is pictured in 1900 photograph'; 'SALTWATER crocodiles have the strongest bite of any living animal, research has shown'; 'Laika Becomes the First Living Animal to Enter Orbit (1957)'; 'The cheetah achieves by far the fastest land speed of any living animal'; 'This Is the First Living Animal Ever Captured By an Electron Microscope'; ~ No surprises there. They all refer to animals for whom living is still in progress, exactly as one would expect from the use of an -ing...