# Never pre-positive adjectives and intransitive prepositions

Tags: prepositions, adjectives

The accepted response to [an earlier question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/334863/is-there-a-name-for-an-adjective-that-cannot-precede-a-noun/334877?noredirect=1#comment1149206_334877) concerning words like *alone*, *asleep* and *alive* places such words in the category of adjectives that simply don't occur in front of the nouns or noun phrases that they modify -- a category labeled as **never-attributive adjectives**.

There are other words that easily modify noun phrases which precede them, such as *here* and *there*.   These words fall under the category of **intransitive prepositions**.

There are strong similarities between how the two categories presented are placed and used.   They both work well in post-positive, predicative and supplemental positions.   They both seem able to modify verbs as well as nouns.   In some cases (alive and asleep, for example), the so-called never-attributive adjectives derive from fused prepositional phrases.

Is there a useful distinction here?   Is there something about never-attributive adjectives that isn't true of intransitive prepositions?

Edit:  Since examples were requested . . . .

Something that's called a restricted adjective:

> Alone, that man can get the job done. -- supplemental placement
>   That man alone can get the job done.  -- post-positive to a noun phrase
>   That man can get the job done alone.  -- post-positive to a finite verb and its two arguments
>   Let him work alone. -- post-positive to a non-finite verb
>   You should keep him alone.  -- predicative argument

Note that supplemental and post-positive to the verb positions carry similar semantics, quite distinct from those of the placement post-positive to the noun.

Something that's called an intransitive preposition:

> Here, this man can get the job done. -- supplemental placement
>   This man here can get the job done.  -- post-positive to a noun phrase
>   This man can get the job done here.  -- post-positive to a finite verb and its two arguments
>   Let him work here.  -- post-positive to a non-finite verb
>   You should keep him here.  -- predicative argument

Ditto.

And, just for giggles, how about an obvious adjective?

> ? Happy, this man can get the job done. -- supplemental placement
>   ? This man happy can get the job done.  -- post-positive to a noun phrase
>   ? This man can get the job done happy.  -- post-positive to a finite verb and its two arguments
>     Let him work happy.  -- post-positive to a non-finite verb
>     You should keep him happy.  -- predicative argument

Note that, if "let him work happy" and "let him work happily" carry the same semantics, it seems possible that "happy" isn't an adjective there.

Further giggles, a transitive prepositional phrase:

> In the dark, this man can get the job done. -- supplemental placement
>   This man in the dark can get the job done.  -- post-positive to a noun phrase
>   This man can get the job done in the dark.  -- post-positive to a finite verb and its two arguments
>   Let him work in the dark.  -- post-positive to a non-finite verb
>   You should keep him in the dark.  -- predicative argument

This man isn't me.   Don't keep me alone and in the dark.   Where is the difference that I can't see?

Later edit:

I do see a difference, but if it's a difference that helps identify prepositions then it suggests that I've presented the labels backwards:  I'm very alone and very in the dark, but I'm not *very here* even when I am very much here.

Comment: Can you give an example where they modify verbs? (In fact example all round would be helpful for readers!)

Comment: Hey @Araucaria, I thought you had an answer in mind and just needed a place to post it.  Did this softball turn out to be a curveball?

Comment: Hi Gary, just hugely busy. Have written half an answer, but will be a couple of days before I get a chance to finish it.

Comment: Well, shame on real life being a distraction from online playtime.

Comment: You already mentioned modification with degree adverbs, like *very*. Here's another criterion: The items *here* and *there* can form [pronominal adverbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronominal_adverb): *hereby*, *hereafter*, *herein*, *thereby*, *thereafter*, *therein* etc.; the items *alone*, *asleep* and *alive* cannot: * *aloneby*, * *asleepafter*, * *alivein*.

Comment: Good observation, @Richard.  "Here" and "there" seem to make suitable objects for prepositions, whether in a fused form like "hereby" or an ordinary transitive phrase like "in here".  Thanks for that.

Comment: Another difference: *here* and *there* can introduce sentences with inversion: *Here comes the bus*, *There goes the Queen of England*. The words *alone* or *alive* cannot do this. * *Alone goes my friend through life*, * *Alive arrived the shipwrecked man on shore*.

Comment: Could anyone explain any of those "happy" examples?