# How is this structure formed? A case of 'inverted adjective'?

Tags: adjectives, phrase-usage, prepositional-phrases

Here are the structures in question:

> Is there a region in the United States of America that has **a
>   pronunciation similar**, .... Tuscany)?

*compare with:*

> ... that has **a similar pronunciation**, .....

Source: [Where is standard American English derived from?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1884/where-is-standard-american-english-derived-from)

I know that some people may ***find this question silly***, but can we actually **write it in inverted form** and **mean the same thing**?

These examples are of course different:

> Someone made **a different pronunciation**

vs

> Someone made **a pronunciation different**

Comment: The comma is in the wrong place. The phrase is _similar or close to_, which is a simple matter of ellipsis: _similar [to] or close to_. Adjectives such as _alone_ or _apart_, which must follow the noun/pronoun, are really truncated prepositional phrases.

Comment: @KarlG Do you have some resources to support your statements? This prepositional phrases, can you elaborate more?

Comment: I happen to have an [open question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/475890/never-pre-positive-adjectives-and-intransitive-prepositions) on that very topic, inspired by the [accepted answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/334863/is-there-a-name-for-an-adjective-that-cannot-precede-a-noun/334877?noredirect=1#334877) to another question on this site.

Comment: Turns out _alone_ is different: contracted from Middle English _all ane_, ‘all/wholly one’.  _Apart_ is directly from Fr., now _à part_, while in _ablaze, adrift_, etc. the _a_ is a reduction of _on_. You can look up any of these postpositive adjectives beginning with _a_ at: https://www.etymonline.com/

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan Great find! I think I will read it for a while and let it seep through my mind :).

Comment: @KarlG thanks for the heads-up. I'll look into it after finishing the other one first.

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan: I didn’t answer your question because the notion of an _intransitive preposition_ is an oxymoron to me, especially since many prepositions are etymologically transitive adverbs or prepositional phrases themselves, like _in/out - side_. I simply don't find that terminology particularly helpful.

Comment: But, @Karl, that question isn't about whether either of those labels is any good.  It's about how the words in those identified groups differ, or whether there even is a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a region in the United States of America that has a pronunciation *similar, or closer,* **to standard American English**?

Typically, we would use "a similar pronunciation" or "a closer pronunciation", placing the adjective before the thing it modifies.   In the example above, these adjectives are themselves modified by the following prepositional phrase.   We typically place prepositional phrases after the thing that they modify.   Also, we don't typically separate a modifier from its modificand.

In the example, we can't do all of the things that we typically do.

- a similar to the standard pronunciation -- separates the adjective and its noun
- a similar pronunciation to the standard -- separates the prepositional phrase from its adjective
- a pronunciation similar to the standard -- places the adjective after the noun, but leaves related things connected

The connections are more important than the word order.   When we have an adjective with its own trailing modifier, we place that entire phrase after the noun.

- a different pronunciation
- a pronunciation different than I expected

> I know that some people may find this question *silly*.

This example also places the adjective after the noun that it modifies.   The typical order for those words in a single phrase is "this silly question".   However, once again, there is a reason to place the adjective where it is.   We're not looking at a single phrase.   Here, the adjective acts as a separate argument of the verb "find".   "This question" is the direct object.   "Silly" is the object complement.

> Someone made a different pronunciation.
>   Someone made a pronunciation different.

In the first, "a different pronunciation" is one noun phrase, acting as the direct object and only argument of "made".   In the second, we can parse "a pronunciation" as the direct object and "different" as the object complement.

Those are different sentences.   They have different connections and they mean different things.

Comment: So, in conclusion, it means different things, right? I want to confirm this since I often hear this structure around me. First time coming to US many years ago, I was especially confused about this sentence: 'I love you different' vs 'I love you differently'. From my experience (gut feeling?) , I love you differently means how s/he loves me differently while 'I love you different' can mean 'I love you for being different' or 'I love you differently compared to other friends'. So, I think this question might spark some discussion about different kind of ellipsis or different interpretation.

Comment: The verbs "find" and "make" license object complements in standard English.  The verb "love" doesn't.  The sentence "I love you different" opens a new can of worms.  I don't have a good answer to the question of what's happening in that sentence.

Comment: @Flonne.....were you to ask a question about "I love you different / differently I might write an answer